# How can I use spectrogram and/or periodogram to plot a PSD?

Tags: matlab, accelerometer, frequency, spectrogram

I have a <1,000,000x1 double> vector of m/s^2 data from an accelerometer. I'd like to create a power spectral density plot of this data (power/hz vs frequency). 
I can run the vector through spectrogram to find frequencies, but I may be using windows incorrectly. I get a <131073x8 complex double> returned but I don't know what it's contents are.
Can I simply use the function periodogram on my vector to plot power/hz vs frequency? I have tried and matlab returns a blank plot.

Support on this would be very appreciated..
Thank you,
Alex

Comment: Can you list the exact Matlab commands you're giving, that result in that complex double array?

Comment: Sure:
x=<nx1 double>;
spec=spectrogram(x);
spec=<mx8 complex double>;

Comment: Is it proper to assign spectrogram to a variable and then plot this, as below in using pwelch? Plotting spectrogram alone gives Hz vs time. Is there a way to use spectrogram to get power/Hz vs Hz?

Comment: What you're getting is the short-time Fourier transform -- basically, each row is the spectral density at 8 equally-spaced windows. Try plotting each of the 8 rows separately; each is an FFT. [This link might be useful](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ug/psd-estimate-using-fft.html) in understanding relation of FFT to power/Hz.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want a plot of the power spectral density, you can run

```
periodogram(x)
```

and you get a plot of the power spectral density (in dB) over *normalized frequency*. If you want the density over *actual frequency* (in Hz), you need to specify the sampling rate of your data. The syntax is

```
periodogram(x, [], [], Fs)
```

where `Fs` is the sampling frequency (in Hz). You then get a plot with a horizontal axis from 0 to `Fs / 2` (the Nyquist frequency).

The two parameters given as `[]` can be used to specify the window length for the periodogram method and the number of data points used for the underlying FFT. You can use these, especially the window length, in order to regulate the trade-off between frequency resolution of the spectrum and the precision to which the power spectral density is estimated.

With none of these syntaxes does `periodogram` return any output. You can however use the syntax

```
[P, f] = periodogram(x, [], [], fs);
```

which returns the estimate of the power spectral density in `P` and the corresponding frequencies (in Hz) in `f`. From this you can generate a plot similar to the one generated by `periodogram` without outputs by using

```
semilogy(f, P)
```

i.e. plotting `P` over `f` with a logarithmic scale for the vertical axis.

Comment: Btw., it is not normally recommended to use the classic periodogram method for spectral estimation. Better would be to use Welch's modified periodogram method, implemented in `pwelch`. Moreover, in order to obtain good results in spectral estimation, I would strongly recommend acquiring the basic textbook knowledge on the topic. There are just too many things that can go wrong if one isn't aware of them.

Comment: Great, thanks. I made two sample cosine functions and tried out periodogram and pwelch. Using pwelch gave peaks closer to the input frequency, though not exactly. (i.e. I put in x=cos(t) and got a freq peak at 0.22, whereas the actual frequency is 1/2*pi which ~= 0.16). Maybe I'm thinking about this wrong. Would you also be able to explain "window"? Let's say I have a vector of 100 points... will "window" default to an appropriate size or will I need to change it?  Same goes for the length of the underlying fft. Thanks again.

Comment: The window is not just about the length, but also about the shape. If you really don't want to get deeper into the issue, I guess the defaults of pwelch should be fine. But seriously, the details of spectral estimation go beyond what I can explain to you in a comment here. At the very least have a look at the Wikipedia pages for [Welch's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch%27s_method) and [window function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function). – Btw., if you think my answer provides what you were looking for, would you mind accepting it?

Comment: How do the functions pwelch and periodogram differ from the function spectrogram? Would it be more appropriate to use spectrogram here?

Comment: A spectrogram is a time-dependent spectral estimate. Which one is appropriate depends on whether you expect the spectral composition of your signal to change over time.